# How to apply a patch in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, patch

I have only a few months android experiece .Recently I updated to android studio 1.2 and the update broke the preview pane , i would like to help with this bug by checking what works and what doesnt ,

It says here in the Known issues page

> Workaround 3: If the above workarounds don't work for you, and you are
>   on windows, please try downloading a build from
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6b7eYGgoFdCTWFyYWlySExjUlE/view
>   which probably solves the issue. Please report back on the issue
>   tracker whether it worked for you or not.

and here is the issue tracker https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170841

I have downloaded the .zip file but have no idea what it means to apply the patch , and i'm currently working on some simple apps and would hate to break the IDE ,

PS: As soon as the bug is fixed i will also switch to the stable update channel

Answer (score 40):

At Android Studio : Top menu Select VCS -> Apply Patch

Answer (score 4):

In my case, using Android Studio Artic Fox. Top Menu: Git -> Patch -> Apply patch (or "Apply Patch from Clipboard" if you have copied it)

Answer (score 0):

Select Git from above Menu Bar and click on Patch, then select either of the two options.

[Click on Image to find this Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrTbq.png)

Docs : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-patches.html#apply-patch

Answer (score -1):

Try lowering the version used to render to API 21

On the right of the preview pane change the 22 to 21.